# Linq Group By with TreeView

Tags: vb.net, linq, treeview, group-by

I am trying to use link to group data and use it directly in treeview1.itemsource.  The 
code I used is:

```
DisksTreeView1.ItemsSource = (From g As Classes.DiskPrime In CurrentVariables.DisksList
                                     Group By g.Genre
                                      Into MyGroup = Group)
```

and Xaml is:

```
<TreeView Name="DisksTreeView1" >
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Namee}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

The class code is:

```
Public Class DiskPrime
        Property ID As String
        Property Namee As String
        Property Genre As String
        Property DateCreated As Date
        Property Path As String   
End Class
```

After running the program I am only getting a blank treeview, could you please correct me where i have done wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `GroupBy` returns an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, DiskPrime>>`, which means you are actually binding to an `IGrouping<string, DiskPrime>` and not to a `DiskPrime`.

To see the group names you could bind to `Key` rather than `Namee`

This will only display the first level though (the group names). In order to see which elements each group contains, you'll need to use `HierarchicalDataTemplate` instead of `DataTemplate`.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but if IGrouping is the result, there where is the list of grouped items, I mean you said that list of  IGrouping<string, DiskPrime> is the result, so how could I know how they are grouped.